# Unable to get Interval data correctly using Angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

Here I am displaying the dynamic data on the table and table will be generated based on the multi drop down selection. If I choose the first drop down option based on that of the second drop down option will be generated and based on this a table will be generated. Every 30 seconds I want to refresh the table/update the tables data previous I used **setInterval()**:

```
return Observable.interval(30000).flatMap(()=>{ 
  return this.http.get(url + data+'/userid='+ param).map(res => { 
     return res.json(); 
  }); 
)};

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap`;
```

This above code is working fine but the issue here is **even though I select a value in the second drop down it is displaying the previous values and all the drop down values**. Also suppose in the drop down I have 1,2,3 in drop down, if 2 is selected it is refreshing 2 for every 30 seconds along with that of 1 and 3. They are also refreshing and I am getting values of them also.

Comment: make sure to unsubscribe the Observable. Also provide with some more code how you are using this or make small project on stackblitz if possible so that it is easy to see the problem.

Comment: This maybe of help: [Angular 2 Repeat Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37938735/repeat-request-angular2-http-get-n-seconds-after-finished/45937660#45937660)

Comment: Need more code to make a dignostic

Comment: Who is param? I think the Observable's scope doesn't get the correct param value. To check it  breakpoint the FlatMap function or sent a console.log with the current param value. If that it the case re-read the param inside the FlatMap function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a given very little information. But i think question can be constructed by it. Some things will be here and there. It answers your question

Things you should know about

1. [Subject](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html): A observable object which can also emit by calling `onNext(...)` on it.
2. [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html): Map to observable, complete previous inner observable, emit values.

Creating two subject.These emits values when user select any options.

```
let firstValue$ = new Subject();
function on1stDropdownChanged(newFirstValue) {
    firstValue$.next(newFirstValue);
}
let secondValue$ = new Subject();
function on2ndDropdownChanged(newSecondValue) {
    secondValue$.next(newSecondValue);
}
```

This return required data based on values passed

```
function getUserData(firstValue, secondValue): Observable<UserData[]> {
    //how ever you want to handle these.
    if (firstValue == undefined || secondValue == undefined)
    return Observable.of([]); //empty results
    return ....
}
```

This return required 2nd dropdown options based on first value passed.

```
function getSecondValues(firstValue): Observable<SecondValue[]> {
    //how ever you want to handle these.
    if (firstValue == undefined) 
    return Observable.of([]); //empty results
    return ....
}
```

Now you need two type of events.

1. When 2nd dropdown is selected.
2. Fetch values when dropdown changes and then every 30 sec passed

We will create a observable which emits when 1st and 2nd value are selected. Some thing may change.

```
let when2ndSelected = firstValue$.switchMap( //When 1st selected, wait for below 
    firstValue =>
        getSecondValues(firstValue) // get second options based on first.
            .do(secondValues=>...) // whatever you want to do with these
            .switchMap(_ => secondValue$) // wait for 2nd selection by user
            .map(secondValue=>[firstValue,secondValue]) // map to first second array
)
```

Now we will do the user fetching

```
let timer = Observable.timer(0, 30000) // emit at 0,30,60sec ... 
let finalData$ = when2ndSelected
    .switchMap(firstSecondValue =>
        timer.switchMap(_time => getUserData(firstSecondValue[0], firstSecondValue[1])) //fetches new request at every 30 seconds.
    )
```

These is approach to the problem. You need tweek it to fit exactly your purpose. But I don't think it should fail.