# Observable - set constant delay between one poll return and another poll start

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I want to create an Observable-based poller that waits a certain amount of time between the previous request returning and the next request going out.

Here's the code I tried, but this sets a delay between requests going out:

```
import {timer} from "rxjs";

    this.timer = timer(1, POLLING_INTERVAL)
     .pipe(concatMap(
        (_) => getData()
      )).subscribe((data) => {
        // do something with data     
      });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Polling server after each server response + delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54344923/polling-server-after-each-server-response-delay)

Answer (score 1):

`timer` isn't ideal for this. Rather use `repeatWhen` with `delay`.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { repeatWhen, delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

getData().pipe(
  repeatWhen(notifications => notifications.pipe(
    delay(POLLING_INTERVAL),
  )),
).subscribe(...);
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-2evzzi

Comment: Won't this delay the first request as well?

Comment: No because `repeatWhen` passes all `next` notifications through and captures only `complete` notifications. If `getData()` emits first `next` and then `complete` then `next` won't be delayed.

Comment: Ok, so this works, except that `getData` needs to be called during each poll, and it depends on changed variables in the closure.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't seem to call `getData` more than once at all, so this isn't what I want.

Comment: @ilancohen If you need to call `getData` each time, then try `defer(()=>getData()).pipe(repeatWhen(...))`. Original answer implied that your logic is contained solely inside source observable subscription logic.

Answer (score 0):

You has to use the creation interval for:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ohddud?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100
Or timer with two parameters:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-h9pzxr?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100

I hope you merge request in a correct way.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question.
I want to:
1. Send a request (i.e. call an async function)  
2. Wait for it to return  
3. Wait X seconds  
4. Send another request, etc.

Comment: Now I understand.